# Qual melhor forma de organizar e trabalhar com rotas em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Qual melhor forma de organizar e trabalhar com rotas em ASP.NET MVC?

Enquanto temos 1, 2 rotas, é tranquilo, mas e quando temos 500 ? 600 ?
Em uma aplicação corporativa há muitas rotas, qual é a melhor forma de organiza-las sem perder o controle/performance ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando o máximo possível de rotas *Default*.

Por exemplo:

```
public class RouteConfig 
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new [] { "SeuProjeto.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Apenas com essas declarações, você tem a rota pra todos os `Controllers` da sua aplicação, tendo por padrão a `Action` *Index* e o parâmetro Id como opcional.

Se o objetivo é ter nomes alternativos para suas rotas, você pode colocar as rotas alternativas antes da rota `Default` ou separar as rotas alternativas em outro arquivo. Se optar pelo caminho da separação, não esqueça de chamar os dois registros de rotas no seu `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RotasAlternativasConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); // Crie um arquivo chamado RotasAlternativasConfig no diretório App_Start
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Para organizar suas rotas, você sempre deve colocar **as mais específicas primeiro** e depois as mais genéricas. Pois assim que o asp.net encontrar uma rota que satisfaça seus parâmetros, ele vai utiliza-lá e ignorar as próximas.

Feito isso, a melhor forma de garantir que você não vai se "perder" com muitas rotas e que tudo continuará funcionando na medida que você cria ou modifica as rotas, é testar as mesmas com Unit Test.

Eu costumo utilizar o pacote nuget **MvcRouteTester** para fazer isso.

```
Install-Package MvcRouteTester
```

Segue abaixo a documentação do mesmo, onde você encontrará exemplos:

https://mvcrouteunittester.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 pelo `MvcRouteTester`. Muito bom.

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). Dá pra visualizar bem as rotas e os valores, além de outras informações detalhadas sobre o que está ocorrendo no servidor.