# O que são rotas em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, terminologia, rotas

Em ASP.NET MVC sempre aparece-me o termo **rota** quando [leio algo relacionado a esta tecnologia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28222/qual-melhor-forma-de-organizar-e-trabalhar-com-rotas-em-asp-net-mvc), entretanto, comecei a estudar APS.NET MVC há pouco tempo e este termo **rota** esta me causando confusões.

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber o que são **rotas** e qual é sua finalidade e também qual é a importância delas em relação a minha aplicação feita em ASP.NET MVC?

<sup>Se possível eu gostaria que vocês dessem exemplos de preferência na linguagem C#. Mas fiquem à vontade para exemplificar em outras linguagens suportadas pelo DotNet.</sup>

Comment: Vinculado: [O que são as actions de um controller?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93728/18246)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que deseja saber sobre o roteamento como um todo. Ele é a forma de direcionar as requisições HTTP recebidas para os devidos métodos do *controller*. Então conforme a informação vem nessa requisição um método diferente será chamado.

A rota é o caminho que ele pegará para executar algo, dependendo do contexto, de alguma forma se confunde com o [URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101). De uma certa forma podemos dizer que é o método dentro da classe. O caminho é decidido de acordo com o verbo do HTTP, das várias partes do URL ou algumas outras informações relevante para tomar uma decisão.

O sistema de roteamento do ASP.NET MVC analisa a requisição recebida, procura por um padrão e usa um critério para decidir o que fazer. Detalhes sobre isso podem ser configurados programaticamente, além do padrão que ele adota por convenção de acordo com as *strings*.

Nas versões antigas ele usava o mesmo sistema de roteamento do ASP.NET clássico. No .NET Core há um sistema próprio.

#Exemplo

Um exemplo de rota criada na classe `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", //nome da rota
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // padrão do URL
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // parâmetros
```

Então o que vier primeiro no início dos parâmetros no URL (em condições normais logo após o domínio e talvez a porta) é o que determinará qual classe *controller* será chamada.

O que vem em seguida como se fosse um subdiretório é a ação, ou seja, o método dessa classe que deverá ser executado. Mas pode ser que outras partes sejam necessárias para determinar o método correto já que os métodos podem ter o [mesmo nome mas assinaturas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), então precisa entender o tipo de dado que será passado se tiver métodos com mesmo nome.

Por fim, nesse exemplo, encontra o que será passado para o método como argumento. Seu tipo poderia ser considerado na assinatura.

Também é configurado o objeto com valores padrão se não vier nada útil para estabelecer a rota.

A classe que vai processar isso seria algo assim:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index(string id) => View();
}
```

Poderia ter uma anotação indicando o [verbo específico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/101) que é aceito.

Poderia chamar assim:

```
dominio.com/Home/Index/101
```

#Atributos

Também é possível definir as rotas com [atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101). Exemplo:

```
[Route(“{produtoId:int}”)]
public ActionResult Edita(int produtoId) => View();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/Route.cs).

#Alternativa à roteamento

Todas rotas formam um mapeamento entre o que vem externamente e o código. Sem as rotas teria que ter um arquivo para cada ação e a interpretação dos argumentos contidos no URL teria que ser feita em cada um desses arquivos. Esse mecanismo cuida do trabalho chato e arriscado facilitando muito o trabalho do programador.

#Conclusão

Tem vários detalhes, mas pela pergunta a ideia básica é essa. Perguntas específicas podem ser interessantes. Consulte antes o que já foi perguntado aqui no site.

- [Documentação do Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc668201(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Documentação do ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html)

Answer (score 5):

As rotas seriam o modo para ter acesso as Actions das Controllers (ou basicamente, a URL).

Exemplo:

Digamos que você tenha uma **Controller** chamada AreaCliente e dentro desta controller tenha uma **Action** chamada ListaCompras.

Pra ter acesso a essa Action, você teria que escrever a URL no seguinte formato:

www.siteexemplo.com/AreaCliente/ListaCompras

Isso basicamente é a Rota.

Sua importância está no acesso as Actions e também no negócio [URL Amigável e SEO (conjunto de boas práticas para aumentar o alcance por site de buscas, como o Google, Bing, etc)]. O MVC possui algumas ferramentas que auxiliam na manutenção dessas rotas. Um exemplo é pelo **RouteConfig**, porém, também disponibilizar alguns outros métodos, como **atributos**.

Um exemplo é o **RoutePrefix**, que se utiliza acima do nome da controller para estabelecer um prefixo (nome para acesso a controller), caso deseje algo mais agradável. Utilizando ainda o exemplo acima, poderíamos usar na seguinte forma:

```
[RoutePrefix("cliente")]
public class AreaCliente : Controller
{
   // Actions ...
}
```

Desta forma, podemos ter a possibilidade de acessar da seguinte maneira:

www.siteexemplo.com/**cliente**/ListaCompras

E pra ajustar melhor ainda, possuímos outro atributo chamado **Route**, este é usado acima da action:

```
[RoutePrefix("cliente")]
public class AreaCliente : Controller
{
    [Route("compras")]
    public ActionResult ListaCompras()
    {
        // código
    }
}
```

E neste caso, acessaríamos no seguinte formato

www.siteexemplo.com/**cliente**/**compras**

Outras características dos atributos é também modular os parâmetros da Action.