# O que significa o termo "routing" no contexto de arquitetura MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, terminologia

Estou iniciando no estudo dessa arquitetura e me deparei com esse termo : `routing`.

***edit***

Preciso de algum `framework` para desenvolver com base nessa arquitetura ?

Comment: Eu sei que é outra tecnologia, mas isso já não responde? Funciona igual. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162142/101

Comment: Sei muito pouco a respeito para afirmar se responde, a primeira vista tentar entender algo pela 1º vez em uma outra linguagem já dificulta um pouco para mim, eventualmente se alguém conseguir postar algo no contexto do php, para mim seria mais fácil entender...

Comment: Só uma nota: Routing ou rotas não está ligado ao MVC, é apenas um funcionalidade de alguns frameworks que combinam duas coisas diferentes, para resumir o MVC não é uma tecnologia, ele seria um "método de organização do projeto" (Padrão de projeto ou do inglês *design pattern*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"Routing"` traduzindo é `"Roteamento"`.

Pelo o que eu entendo de MVC, o termo *Routing* está relacionado ao controle/definção de rotas de uma aplicação.

Essas *rotas* geralmente são utilizadas para definir uma ação que será executada quando determinada url for acessada.

Exemplo: redirecionamentos, resposta em `json` ou `html`.

## Exemplo em Frameworks

É muito comum a utilização de rotas em frameworks PHP que utilizam o padrão MVC.

Vou dar um exemplo de definição de rotas no framework chamado Laravel.

Exemplo:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');

Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@getAbout');
```

Basicamente, na declaração acima, você está definindo duas rotas. Cada uma efetua uma ação diferente, para cada `path` diferente (`path` é a parte da url que fica depois da `/`).

Ou seja, quando alguém acessar a url `meusite.com.br` o método `getIndex` de `HomeController` será invocado. Porém, se acessar `meusite.com.br/about`, será invocado `getAbout`.

Ainda em relação ao termo *Routing*, não poderia deixar de citar que os frameworks Symfony e Laravel utilizam esse termo `Routing` internamente em seus `namespaces`.

Esses frameworks são separados por várias bibliotecas. E em uma destas, existe uma chamada de *Routing*. Isso porque os desenvolvedores desses dois frameworks tiveram a ideia de criar toda a estrutura de roteamento separado em uma biblioteca específica.

É importante citar que as funcionalidades atribuídas ao *roteamento* das bibliotecas citadas acima vão além de uma definição de uma ação para cada url. No sistemas de *roteamento* desses frameworks, outras responsabilidades são atribuidas a essa biblioteca. São elas:

- Definição de filtros. Uma rota só poderá ser acessada de acordo com uma condição. Por exemplo, um usuário autenticado pode acessar uma rota `a`, mas um não autenticado não pode.
- Coleção de rotas. Uma classe responsável por registrar todas as informações das rotas.
- Tratamento de erros. Caso a url acessada represente uma rota não definida, uma ação padrão deverá ser chamada.
- Verificação do verbo da requisição. Nesse caso, trata-se de saber se a rota aceita requisições do tipo POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc. É útil fazer essa verificação para aplicações Restful.

## Bibliotecas de roteamento

**Biblioteca de `Routing` do Symfony e Laravel**

As bibliotecas citadas acima encontram-se atualmente no Github. Se quiser dar uma olhada para saber como foi feita a organização das mesmas, dê uma olhada nelas:

- [Symfony/Routing](https://github.com/symfony/routing)
- [Illuminate/Routing [Laravel]](https://github.com/illuminate/routing)

**Biblioteca `Routes` do PHPLegends**

A biblioteca `PHPLegends/Routes` possui uma forma bem simples de você criar um sistema de rotas, sem dependência de um framework.

- [PHPLegends/Routes](https://github.com/phplegends/routes)

Exemplo (similar ao exemplo anterior):

```
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new \PHPLegends\Routes\Router;

$router->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

$router->get('/about', function () {
    return 'About me!';
});

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '/';

$dispatcher = new \PHPLegends\Routes\Dispatcher($page, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

echo $router->dispatch($dispatcher);
```

<sub>**Nota**: Eu contribuo com o desenvolvimento dessa última biblioteca citada.</sub>

Comment: Não mano esquece Asp.net, é php....

Comment: Tem de usar framework ?

Comment: Tem como colocar um exemplo do uso em php sem `framework` ?

Comment: @MagicHat to resolvendo um BO de Mysql. Vou melhorar pra vocÊ

Comment: De boa man...sem pressa...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters só uma pergunta, no caso em MVC, a questao de filtros de uma rota nao deveria estar relacionada diretamente com o model? Por exemplo, se o usuário nao estiver logado ele nao pode acesssar a rota.. quem analisa isso é o model certo? Ou vc tem que "escrever" isso na rota também? Desculpa voltar no assunto.

Comment: +1 pela resposta.. muito boa!

Answer (score 8):

Não é necessário frameworks para criar nada, você só precisará de um framework se não dispor de tempo ou achar que o framework é "bom" e lhe atende, frameworks foram criados por pessoas assim como nós, mas geralmente são mantidos por comunidades maiores (2 ou mais pessoas).

Resumindo em qualquer linguagem é possível fazer qualquer coisa que outro framework tenha feito.

Agora o ponto mais importante, **routing** ou **rotas** não estão ligados ao MVC, é apenas um funcionalidade de alguns frameworks que combinam duas coisas diferentes, para resumir o **MVC não é uma tecnologia**, ele é "método de organização do projeto" (*Padrão de projeto* ou do inglês *design pattern*).

As rotas se referem as URLs e as vezes dominios que são repassados em forma de váriavel para o PHP, um exemplo *bastante simples* e sem framework usando o Apache seria isto isto (a maioria dos servidores é Apache):

1. Crie um arquivo chamado `.htaccess` na pasta do teu projeto (na mesma pasta do teu index.php) com o seguinte conteúdo:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri_path=$1
   ```
2. Na mesma pasta, no index.php faça isto:

   ```
   <?php

   $uri_path = empty($_GET['uri_path']) ? null : $_GET['uri_path'];

   $rotas = array(
      '/'         => 'pages/home.php', //Este será a index se acessado http://localhost/projeto/
      '/sobre'    => 'pages/about.php',
      '/carrinho' => 'pages/cart.php',
      '/admin'    => 'pages/admin/home.php', //Pagina para o seu "dashboard"
      '/perfil'   => 'outro/foo/bar/script_de_perfil.php'
   );

   $paginaAtual = empty($rotas[$uri_path]) ? null : $rotas[$uri_path];

   if ($paginaAtual) {
       //Chama a página
       include $paginaAtual;
   } else {
       include 'error/404.php';
   }
   ```

Isto é um exemplo bem simples como já citei, para passar argumentos como `http://localhost/projeto/perfil-{id}` e pegar o `id` seria necessário `preg_match`, mas ae seria outra historia.

Não existe um padrão para as fazer as rotas, você pode criar uma padrão próprio, usar algo semelhante ao dos frameworks conhecidos

Comment: Orra fico legal essa explicação... Consegui captar...Vlw man...

Comment: Apesar de a pergunta ter sido especificamente sobre MVC, foi importante citar que é possível criar uma organização de rotas, sem precisar de frameworks, biblioteca e afins.  +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas eu falei de MVC, isto não é tecnologia e não está ligado as rotas, o que acontece é que frameworks usam o design pattner MVC para organizar o projeto e transferem as rotas para acesso a um ou mais Controllers, mas no final que define se é MVC mesmo é o desenvolvedor, você pode usar Laravel e ainda sim não estar fazendo MVC :)

Comment: Ah, é verdade, que vacilo!

Answer (score 0):

É, a grosso modo, as urls que vamos usar para o acessos a nosso sistema. Por exemplo, se eu quero criar uma view que me permite cadastrar um usuário eu preciso definir uma rota tanto para chegar nesta view quanto para passar para outra view ao finalizar o cadastro. O routing, nos permite gerenciar como nossa aplicação vai interagir, seja para passar de uma view para outra seja para passar funções do controller.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de como seria feito esse `routing`, algum código...